# How to set compilerOptions.isCustomElement for VueJS 3 in Laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, compiler-errors, vuejs3

I'm working on VueJS 3 inside Laravel project and I'm using a JS file which providing me with elements that I use for markdown toolbar. Basically it's a set of functions that provides me with buttons that applies the selected markdown option. Everything works just fine but I'm getting those console errors that I want them to gone.

They are all similar to this one:

```js
Failed to resolve component: md-linedivider
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <Markdowntoolbar> 
  at <Article onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft" leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__bounceOutUp" mode="out-in" > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> 
  at <Bodycomponent> 
  at <App>
```

This is saying that md-linedivider element should be excluded from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. And I really looked everywhere for a solution and I only found [this one](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/yarnpkg-where-to-set-compileroptions/125040/7) but I don't have vue.config.js in my laravel project to apply that to. I tried to do this in webpack.mis.js and app.js but it didn't work.

Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this in your **webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue({
  options: {
    compilerOptions: {
      isCustomElement: (tag) => ['md-linedivider'].includes(tag),
    },
  },
});
```

---

UPDATE 4.8.22 - for Vite projects: **vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => ['md-linedivider'].includes(tag),
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

Comment: Can you update your answer for what if we're using Vite and not webpack.mix anymore?

Answer (score 35):

For Nuxt3 you can set value in `nuxt.config.ts` as shown blow.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vue: {  
    compilerOptions: {
      isCustomElement: (tag) => ['lite-youtube'].includes(tag),
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: It indeed works, if you need more than 1 element then try `isCustomElement: (tag: string) => tag.startsWith('v-' && 'nuxt'),` (edit: `v-` is for `Vuetify`, you can replace it according to your needs)

Comment: Does someone know something about the config to Nuxt2?

Comment: Thank you! Confirmed working for Nuxt 3. 

Answer (score 12):

### vue.js with vite:

in your `vite.config.js/ts`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => {
            return tag.startsWith('ion-') // (return true)
          }
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

---

### With a `Vue.js that includes the runtime compiler (aka "full build")` you can do it this way:

in your `main.js/ts`

```js
// treat all tags starting with 'ion-' as custom elements
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => {
  return tag.startsWith('ion-') // (return true)
}
```

### see vue3 docs on this topic: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-compileroptions

Answer (score 10):

Also i have faced this mistake in Vue3,  in the code i wrote **component** : but it must be **components** . I think it gives that warning in typing errors.

Comment: really helpful comment

Comment: Just found out the error was because of a **typo** on the component name <3

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

Vue likes to know if the developer use custom Elements. For this case you can use the Vue compnents property.

```js
import MdLinedivider from "../path/file.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MdLinedivider
  },
  ...
}
```

Afterwards then you can use: `<md-linedivider />` or `<MdLinedivider />` Tag in your HTML.

Comment: Is it for vue2, vue3 or both ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a global component named `view`, but i used it as `View`。 That's why I got the warning.

Answer (score 1):

This library deals with custom components, very straightforward: https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components

```js
// vite.config.ts
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    Components({ /* options */ }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Is your app not working properly after adding `compilerOptions`**? ... Read below...

---

Your ***warnings*** may had ***cleared out*** after implementing something like so:

I'm using Vuetify, so I needed to add all the custom elements starting with `v-`

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => {
            return tag.startsWith('v-') 
          }
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

Clearing out the warnings is a good thing, but if your app is ***NOT working properly*** anymore, consider creating a `vitest.config.ts` file.

This way the Vitest test script will do the testings using a different configuration specified in `vitest.config.ts` and the `build` or `dev` script will use the configuration specified in `vite.config.ts`.

To do this:

Copy paste your code from `vite.config.ts` into `vitest.config.ts` and remove the `compilerOptions` or `template` from the `vue()` plugin, leaving your `vite.config.ts` the way it was.

Make sure to follow the [configuration properly in the docs](https://vitest.dev/config/#configuration)

And it will all work as nice as it can get ✔️

Answer (score 1):

After 10 hours of trying, it turned out that in my particular case, **the child component was importing the parent component** - even though it was not used and was just left over from refactoring and rearranging the code. The simple fact that it imported it seemed to confuse the order in which components are created.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Vue 3 and Vite project, the issue was that I defined components as an array instead of an object.

```
import MyComponent from "@/components/common/MyComponent";
//components: [MyComponent] <-- DID NOT work 
components: {MyComponent}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I omitted setup attribute inside the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you create two components property

```js
  components: {
    Field
  },
  
  components: {
    Test
  }
```

in your js file, you will face this issue.